# PhotoViewer not known as ionic-native

Tags: image, ionic2, zooming, photoviewer

I installed the PhotoViewer as explained in: https://github.com/sarriaroman/photoviewer

When I add import like this the project:
import {PhotoViewer} from 'ionic-native';

it doesn't compile and it says that PhotoViewer is not part of 'ionic-native'

Anyone knows why?

Comment: which version of ionic-native?

Answer (score 0):

import { PhotoViewer } from '@ionic-native/photo-viewer'

http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-viewer/

Fix your import. Just 'ionic-native' won't work.